# C does not gives real result when with doubles

Tags: c, double, rsa, pki, pow

I'd like to just calculate and print value of variables such as; 65^17, 2760^2345 etc.

when i define variables and calculate normally;

```
double x=65,y=17;

double pw = pow(x,y);

printf("%.0lf\n", pw);
```

the result is always **6599743590836591791911496318976** but the real value is different. When i do this with ubuntu calculator or any other calculators; the result is **6,599743591×10³⁰** so my c file or gcc or whatever it is not shows the real value of pow function.

How can i correct it? I am using ubuntu 13.10 x64 and gcc 4.8.1.

the real problem is when i try to take mod of the result with fmodl(pw,t); where t is 3233, result is printed 887. But if you calculate via calculator result was shown like you said 9 digits etc. when click on mod and write 3233 on a calculator the correct result appears as it is **2790**. You can try it yourself.

Comment: um what? the second value is the first one rounded to 9 decimal places. What's the problem?

Comment: double does not have arbitrary precision; you need [mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org/) or [gmp](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: C never gives imaginary result (whether it is defined or undefined). Trust me!

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/ to help understand floating point numbers represented by a finite number of bits.

Comment: @haccks: *Undefined*, sure.  But never imaginary :-)

Comment: @EricJ.; Of course :)

Comment: @H2CO3; The problem is that they doesn't seem to be equal (in length :P).

Comment: the real problem is when i try to take mod of the result with fmodl(pw,t); where t is 3233, result is printed 887. But if you calculate via calculator result was shown like you said 9 digits etc. when click on mod and write 3233 on a calculator the correct result appears as it is 2790. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Because a 64-bit `double` can only give you about 19 decimal digits...

Comment: And what i have to do is using a outsource library to support all decimal digits?

Comment: @akikara: To support arbitrary precision, yes you need a library.  See the comment from Elliott Frisch for two options.